# Perl - Determinant of Matrix Containing Variables

Tags: perl, matrix, determinants

I have a Perl program containing the following methods:

- **det** To find the determinant of a matrix.
- **identityMatrix** Return an n by n identity matrix (1s on the main diagnal, rest 0s).
- **matrixAdd** To add two matrices together.
- **matrixScalarMultiply** To multiply an integer by a matrix.

I can easily find the determinant of, for example, a matrix **A - I** where

[image]

(It is 0)

But what if I want to find the determinant of **A - RI**?

[image]

In this case, I want my program to solve for the characteristic polynomial solution (a.k.a. the determinant containing variables) along these lines instead of an integer value:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to handle this?  Code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#perl Solver.pl

use strict;
use warnings;

### solve the characteristic polynomial det(A - RI) 

my @A = ( # 3x3, det = -3
   [1, 3, -3],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 0],
);

# test_matrix = A - I
my $test_matrix = matrixAdd( \@A, 
    matrixScalarMultiply( identityMatrix(3), -1 ) );

print "\nTest:\n";
for( my $i = 0; $i <= $#$test_matrix; $i++ ){ 
    print "[";
    for( my $j = 0; $j <= $#$test_matrix; $j++ ){
        $j == $#$test_matrix ? print $test_matrix->[$i][$j], "]\n" : 
            print $test_matrix->[$i][$j], ", ";
    }
}

my $dd = det ($test_matrix);
print "det = $dd \n";



# recursively find determinant of a real square matrix
# only call on n by n matrices where n >= 2
#
# arg0 = matrix reference
sub det{
    my ($A) = @_;

    #base: 2x2 matrix
    if( $#$A + 1 == 2 ){ #recall $#$A == last index of A
        return $A->[0][0]*$A->[1][1] - $A->[1][0]*$A->[0][1];
    }

    #cofactor expansion for matrices > 2x2
    my $answer = 0;
    for( my $col = 0; $col <= $#$A; $col++ ){
        my $m = (); #sub matrix
        my $multiplier = $A->[0][$col];
        if( $col % 2 == 1 ){    #+, -, +, -, ...
            $multiplier *= -1;
        }

        for( my $i = 1; $i <= $#$A; $i++ ){ 
            #j is indexer for A, k for m
            for( my ($j, $k) = (0, 0); $j <= $#$A; $j++ ){
                $m->[$i-1][$k++] = $A->[$i][$j] unless $j == $col;
            }
        }

        $answer += $multiplier*det( $m );
    }#end cofactor expansion

    return $answer;
}#end det()


# return reference to an n by n identity matrix
# can do this in Perl!
#
# arg0 = dimension 'n'
sub identityMatrix{
    my $n = shift;
    my @ret;

    for (my $i = 0; $i < $n; $i++ ){
        for (my $j = 0; $j < $n; $j++ ){
            $ret[$i][$j] = $i == $j ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }

    return \@ret;   
}


# return reference to an n by n matrix which is the sum
# of two different n by n matrices, "a" and "b"
#
# arg0, 1 = references to the pair of matrices to add
sub matrixAdd{
    my @ret;
    my ($a, $b) = ($_[0], $_[1]);

    for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#$a; $i++ ){
        for (my $j = 0; $j <= $#$a; $j++ ){
            $ret[$i][$j] = $a->[$i][$j] + $b->[$i][$j];
        }
    }

    return \@ret;
}


# return reference to a matrix multiplied by a given scalar
#
# arg0 = reference to matrix
# arg1 = scalar to multiply by
sub matrixScalarMultiply{
    my @ret;
    my ($a, $multiplier) = ($_[0], $_[1]);

    for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#$a; $i++ ){
        for (my $j = 0; $j <= $#$a; $j++ ){
            $ret[$i][$j] = $a->[$i][$j] * $multiplier;
        }
    }

    return \@ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called symbolic math and is in the wheelhouse of [tools like Mathematica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems). For Perl, there are packages like [`Math::Synbolic`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Symbolic) but I couldn't tell you how easy they are to use.

On the other hand, if you are just interested in what values of *R* have a determinant of zero and not that interested in what the characteristic polynomial looks like, then you are looking for the [*eigenvalues*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Eigenvalue.html) of *A*. [There are some Perl libraries for that](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::MatrixDecomposition::Eigen), too.

Comment: I thought it could be a good exercise to figure out how to (1) solve for a matrix's characteristic polynomial and (2) solve for the roots (eigenvalues) without using a library, but I guess it'll be much harder than I thought.  I think I'll start using some libraries soon.  Thanks!